# .gitignore is not ignoring files when I push with branch

Tags: git, github

I have two branches to my project, master and test branches . when I'm at branch test, I edited the file .gitignore I added vendor/* . but for some reason when I do git push origin test:master it still push files in vendor. is there any way to flush the cache or something like that to make sure it is working ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Push is not your issue. It's what you're committing. Pushing just transfers commits that already exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess here is that you had files tracked by git in your `vendor` directory prior to filling `.gitignore`.

In which case the behavior you see is normal: the git index knows about these files and tracks their contents. If you fill your .gitignore after git tracks the file, it is too late, it will only ignore files you add from this point on.

What you need to do is unreference these files (or "untrack"), so that the index does not know about them anymore -- but without deleting them. For this, use the `--cached` option of `git rm`:

```
git rm -r --cached vendor
```

Then commit the result. From now on, and as you have filled .gitignore, the `vendor` directory will be ignored.

Note that you will have to repeat this operation for each and every branch in which you have files tracked in this directory.

And finally, there is a more destructive way, and as such very dangerous: `git filter-branch`. But you want to do that as a last resort, and only if you really need this.

Comment: Actually I did exactly what you said, then committed the results and pushed it, but when I tried to get back to the master branch 'git checkout master' , I got an Error **error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:** , check this out please  https://gist.github.com/78a691a7106189f5ea61 , any clue ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Yep, looks like the situation I described: you have other branches with "vendor" files in them... Rename "vendor" to something else before checking out -- and repeat the manipulation on the master branch as well

Comment: Actually I used git clean  -d  -fx "" , anyways I deleted the files this way :) but still it seems to be working and I have a backup version just in case , your help is highly appreciated , cheers

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering here, but since it's urgent I can't stop myself of asking, after doing that and removed the files, it seems that whenever I make push I still use the same files ( even the files that I deleted ) , i'm pretty sure it is cached , so how am I supposed to flush the cache somehow ?